# Create menu from SharePoint list

Tags: web-part

I have a list named MenuList which contains two columns Title and Url.

I want to create a menu in webpart which should pull data from above list and display its title field only but while clicking the menu, it should redirect me to the URL mentioned on another URL column.

Comment: Why can't you use out of the box Link List? It gives the exact feature you are looking for.

Comment: I am new to SharePoint. It will be helpful if you could explain it as bit more.

Comment: Show your code here how did you create webpart?

Answer (score -1):

To achieve this, we can make use of OOTB webpart that is Content Query Webpart.
All you need to do is, create a webpart zone on your content page(or use existing one) in my case it was right pan.

Now just drag content query webpart by clicking add webpart from you webpart zone.
Once draged, You have to edit it's properties and from edit webpart wizard, you have to set list name and title, url property with your list's title and url field name respectively(If you want to set desciption and picture field, that can also be mapped but optional).

Finally click on apply/ok and then publish the page.